How to overlay image with transparent background using emgu cv?
I want to overlay image1 with image2. But, image2 having transparent background. In this case , it shown as black overlayed image.
public void Drawbell(Image<Bgr, byte> image, string Icon, List<Coordinate> polygonVertices, MCvScalar fillScalar)
  {
      
          Image<Bgr, byte> bellIcon = new Image<Bgr, byte>(Icon);

          Image<Bgr, byte> resizedIcon = bellIcon.Resize(100, 100, Inter.Linear);


          // Calculate the centroid of the polygon
          Coordinate centroid = CalculateCentroid(polygonVertices);

          int rectX = centroid.X - resizedIcon.Width / 2;
          int rectY = centroid.Y - resizedIcon.Height / 2;

          // Center the icon at the centroid
          rectX = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(rectX, image.Width - resizedIcon.Width));
          rectY = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(rectY, image.Height - resizedIcon.Height));

          var mask = resizedIcon.Convert<Gray, byte>().SmoothGaussian(1).ThresholdBinaryInv(new Gray(254), new Gray(255)).Erode(1);
          image.ROI = new Rectangle(rectX, rectY, resizedIcon.Width, resizedIcon.Height);

          image.SetValue(fillScalar, mask);

          resizedIcon.SetValue(fillScalar, mask.Not());
          image._Or(resizedIcon);
          resizedIcon.CopyTo(image);
          image.ROI = Rectangle.Empty;
     
  }

